# Moving the position of a firebase realtime database child node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is a basic Firebase Realtime database node

```
- foo
|--- -LK7rNAPKZP7drHK1eb_
|--- -LKAPfu2lLl2B5zInIhX
|--- -LKJN97VxOhnE8XoNSQN
```

Lets imagine that the foo node has thousands of child nodes.

What is the easiest most effecient method to take for example the middle child node "-LKAPfu2lLl2B5zInIhX" and move to the very bottom position under "-LKJN97VxOhnE8XoNSQN"

Want to get basic idea before I start to attempt this. Any ideas/suggestions would be welcomed.

FYI - I am doing this in Javascript

Comment: The order of keys that you see in the console is fixed.  It's just the lexicographic (alphabetical) ordering of the keys.  There is no "move" operation for child keys.  If you want the children to be ordered, put some child value under each of them that you can use in a query to order them.

Comment: Each of my child nodes already has a unique timestamp value... What would be the best way to pull the database reference feed of "foo" ordered by each childs value called timestamp? So for example: "-LK7rNAPKZP7drHK1eb_" contains "timestamp" which is unique based on Date object.

Comment: It sounds like you should read up on how to do queries with Realtime Database.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Comment: Thanks. Will review  :)

Comment: @Frank, im still facing issue... i can use the .orderByChild('timeStamp') ... i have set a .indexOn for timeStamp in my security... When I try to call the .orderByChild with .startAt .... I get null data back. When I remove .startAt I get the initial data ordered by timestamp. The timestamp values I have in the database are Date.now() timestamps. When I try to run the .startAt(Date.now().toString()) it does not work. I need to be able to grab the records by setting the startAt but I never get any returned records. What am I missing?

Comment: Nevermind, seems that I should have been using .endAt for my case. Now it fine.